# Is multiplying hashes a valid way to ensure two sets of data are identical (but in arbitrary order)

Tags: hash, javascript, tampering

Let's say "User A" has a set of data like below. Each entry has been hashed (sha256) to ensure integrity within a single entry. You can't modify data of a single entry without also modifying the corresponding hash:

```
[
{ data: "000000", hash: "91b4d142823f7d20c5f08df69122de43f35f057a988d9619f6d3138485c9a203" }, 
{ data: "111111", hash: "bcb15f821479b4d5772bd0ca866c00ad5f926e3580720659cc80d39c9d09802a" }, 
{ data: "345345", hash: "dbd3b3fcc3286d927ec214c5648fbb226353a239789750f51430b1e6e9d91f4f" }, 
]
```

And "User B" has the same data but in a slightly different order. Hashes are the same of course:

```
[
{ data: "345345", hash: "dbd3b3fcc3286d927ec214c5648fbb226353a239789750f51430b1e6e9d91f4f" }, 
{ data: "111111", hash: "bcb15f821479b4d5772bd0ca866c00ad5f926e3580720659cc80d39c9d09802a" }, 
{ data: "000000", hash: "91b4d142823f7d20c5f08df69122de43f35f057a988d9619f6d3138485c9a203" }, 
]
```

I want to **allow both users to verify they have the exactly same set of data, ignoring sort order**. If, as an extreme example, a hacker is able to replace User B's files with otherwise valid-looking data, the users should be able to compare a hash of their entire datasets and detect a mismatch.

I was thinking to calculate a "total hash" which the users could compare to verify. It should be next to impossible to fabricate a valid looking dataset that results in the same "total hash". But since the order can change, it's a bit tricky.

I might have a possible solution, but I'm not sure if it's secure enough. Is it, actually, secure at all?

My idea is to convert each sha256 hash to integer (javascript BigInt) and multiply them with modulo to get a total hash of similar length:

```
 var entries = [
{ data: "345345", hash: "dbd3b3fcc3286d927ec214c5648fbb226353a239789750f51430b1e6e9d91f4f" }, 
{ data: "111111", hash: "bcb15f821479b4d5772bd0ca866c00ad5f926e3580720659cc80d39c9d09802a" }, 
{ data: "000000", hash: "91b4d142823f7d20c5f08df69122de43f35f057a988d9619f6d3138485c9a203" }, 
];

var hashsize = BigInt("0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff");
var totalhash = BigInt(1); // arbitrary starting point

for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
  var entryhash = BigInt("0x" + entries[i].hash);
  totalhash = (totalhash * entryhash) % hashsize; 
}
totalhash = totalhash.toString(16); // convert from bigint back to hex string
```

This should result in the same hash for both User A and User B, unless other has tampered data, right? How hard would it be to create a slightly different, but valid-looking dataset that results in the same total checksum? Or is there a better way to accomplish this (without sorting!).

Comment: Use Merkle Tree.

Comment: @kelalaka Thank you, Merkle Tree indeed looks like a correct solution to the problem. But it seems implementing that would involve a lot of reading and searching in the entries database to maintain it. I was hoping for a solution that would work in a "rolling basis" with no need to search or sort previous entries when appending new ones. This integrity checking would reside on a very low level, append-only data storage with tens of thousands of entries, not optimized for random reads. Having just few global variables to track when appending would be desireable. Maybe it is not possible...

Comment: What if one file would hash to `0x0`?

Comment: @MechMK1 Haha! Yeah, that would be very, very bad. Nice catch. Although unlikely in normal use, possibly exploitable. That's easy fix though, with a +1 somewhere.